# Find Facebook friends who have existing accounts on Spotify

Tags: facebook, api, spotify

Found out that Spotify Web API does not have an available endpoint for the current user's list of followed users.

So I was wondering if there is a way through the Facebook API to get a list of friends who has a Spotify account?

And for the friends with a Spotify account - getting their Spotify user IDs?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely no way. You can only get friends who authorized YOUR app too with the Facebook API, and there is no relation to the Spotify app. They even have different IDs, because they are App Scoped.

Comment: That's what I thought too, thanks for the confirmation